# How do I make a list of Global Variables in one Visual Basic project available to all projects?

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a series of programs in Visual Basic and have a list of Global Variables I wish to use in most of these programs.  I am not keen on simply listing the global variables at the top of a form in each program because if the list is changed, it has to be redone for each program.

Is one possibility to establish a library of these global variables?

What other alternative is there?

Comment: New Project/Windows/Class Library... or done everything in module.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Library Project.
Add a Class and declare all Globals as Public Shared.

```
Class MyGlobals
    Public Shared Property Global1 As String
    Public Shared Property Global2 As Integer
    Public Shared Property Global3 As Double
    Public Shared Property Global4 As MyType
    .
    .
End Class
```

Add reference to the output dll in all your project and use the global values.

OR

Create a base class with all these global values declared and inherit in all the required classes.